# ROS/ MoveIt! ERROR: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints

Tags: c++, ros, moveit

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.wilselby.com/research/ros-integration/3d-mapping-navigation) to integrate quadcopters into MoveIt!

I need help trying to execute paths. I think I've done everything right till where I do the launch. When I launch, the RVIZ pops up and the quadcopter appears. Then I press 'plan' on the rviz and I can see a shadow moving from where my quadcopter is to where I want it to be (my goal). The problem is when I press 'execute', to actually go to the goal, I have the following errors:

> [ERROR]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ virtual_joint ]
>
> [ERROR]: Known controllers and their joints:
> *In which appears none, or it doesn't have any known controllers*

And then I get the following info:

> [INFO]: ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution

I've tried searching online for this error, but I don't seem to find a solution. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the MultiDofFollowJointTrajectoryAction package given in the link https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator/tree/master/action_controller? Since that is the controller loaded by moveit through the controllers.yaml file in moveit config.

Comment: Also, make sure you are running the action_controller node as given in the tutorial at: <node name="action_controller" pkg="action_controller" type="action_controller" ></node>

Comment: Hello @Saisai3396 thanks for replying.
Yes, I've downloaded the package action_controller and it is in my workspace, and I did the command 'catkin_make' (if this is what you mean by installing). I also have that node in my launch file...

Comment: In fact, I didn't download that package, I've downloaded this one:
https://github.com/AlessioTonioni/Autonomous-Flight-ROS/tree/master/ROS%20-%20Indigo/action_controller from Alessio Tonioni, this one has the srv and msg_gen required by the actionlib.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the ros-controllers package installed

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-ros-controllers
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the modified files from Alessio's package over the original moveit simple controller manager package at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/master/moveit_plugins.
(i.e. clone the original repo for the simple controller manager first from the link then overwrite or add in the extra files present in Alessio's package). Then after this compile.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are launching the gazebo.launch file created by moveit setup_assistant

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).